# Postgres: How to combine columns into the same row value

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I combine multiple columns that could fit into the same row instead of having the same row display many times?

```
flight               | Manager   | Lead  | Worker
---------------------|-----------|-------|--------
Arizona_BGS_Flight_2 | John      |       |
Arizona_BGS_Flight_2 |           | Will  |
Arizona_BGS_Flight_2 |           |       | James
Utah_UTS_Flight_5    | John      |       |
```

Into:

```
flight               | Manager   | Lead  | Worker
---------------------|-----------|-------|--------
Arizona_BGS_Flight_2 | John      | Will  | James
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select flight, max(manager) as manager, max(lead) as lead, max(worker) as worker
from t
group by flight;
```